# Running xfce4-power-manager as daemon with ubuntu 14.04 and awesome

Tags: suspend, power-management, xfce, awesome, xfce4-power-manager

I'm running default ubuntu 14.04 in combination with awesome WM 3.5.9. To enable proper suspend when I close my laptop lid I enable xfce4 after login through the following awesome command which makes xfce4-power-manager unresponsive:

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("xfce4-power-manager")
```

when running "ps -ef | grep xfce4-power-manager" I get the following:

```
test     2277  2273  0 19:28 ?        00:00:00 xfce4-power-manager
test    11842  2365  0 19:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto xfce4-power-manager
```

so xfce4-power-manager is running unresponsively. However if I change the awful execute to "--no-daemon" mode, it runs perfectly. But not running this sort of process in daemon mode doesn't seem like the proper sollution. Has anyone experienced this problem as well and knows a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately running it as daemon didn't succeed. I have solved it (ugly way) by setting the following in awesome WM:

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon")
```

You can also pass the same command to the "run_once" function.